# Python SubProcess For Awk

Tags: python, unix, awk, subprocess, pipe

I am trying to use this awk command in Python with subprocess but I am not sure how I can do the double pipe. I would rather not use `shell=True` as it's poor practice. I have been able to incorporate other awk commands but none of them required double pipe.

`awk 'FNR==NR{if($0~/name: /){line=FNR};next} FNR<=line || FNR>(line+4)' file.txt file.txt`

This removes 4 lines after the last occurrence of "name". Here is the content of my file originally:

```
name: file1
name: file2
name: file3




file4
file5
file6
```

Running this command in the terminal will return:

```
name: file1
name: file2
name: file3
file4
file5
file6
```

I am trying to use python subprocess to do this from within a python file but I'm not sure how to.

Here is my initial approach:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess as sb

sb.Popen('awk','FNR==NR{if($0~/name: /){line=FNR};next} FNR<=line || FNR>(line+4)','file.txt','file.txt')
```

This is the error I get:

`TypeError: bufsize must be an integer`

Any help on how to do this WITHOUT `shell=True`?

Comment: As for || In AWK it is OR not a "double pipe".

Comment: @SlawomirDziuba How silly of me. Thank you for clarifying that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the arguments for the command in a list (`[]`), or they'll end up being assigned to `bufsize`, `executable`, etc. instead of where you want them to go:

```
sb.Popen(['awk','FNR==NR{if($0~/name: /){line=FNR};next} FNR<=line || FNR>(line+4)','file.txt','file.txt'])
```

It has nothing to do with `||`.